# Is there offline alternative to Workflowy?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

Is there any **offline** Workflowy alternative with breadcrumb navigation, click on bullet to "Zoom" and ability to paste image inside notes.

[image]

The closest I found was **Taskpaper** but it doesn't have breadcrumb navigation, "Zoom" into bullet and ability to paste image inside notes.

Answer (score 3):

Workflowy has a desktop (electron) app with offline access as of October 2017 https://blog.workflowy.com/2017/10/19/the-workflowy-desktop-app-has-arrived/

Comment: Thankyou for reply . I have tried it , it requires to login , i dont want to sync to workflowy server